# laravel after change domain dont work links

Tags: laravel-5

Laraval project was in development mode on public IP without domain. Everything worked perfectly, but after changing DNS in my domain to public IP, the project laravel works only on the main page and all links https://mainpage.com/links show The requested URL was not found on this server.

all commands used, without help

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan route:cache
```

.env changed APP_URL=http://mainpage.com

when i change APP_DEBUG=true dont work

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Your error is strange, make sure your domain is pointing to public directory and configured properly. Also remove vendor folder and try to install it again by running `composer install` on your terminal.

Comment: Did you try to debug the issue using: `php artisan route:list ` to list your routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution, problem was with apache virtualhost conf file.

missing:

```
<Directory /home/user/projects/laravel_project/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```